# How to force display through PCI video card when onboard graphics is not working?

Tags: graphics-card, pci

I have an old motherboard. The problem is that its on board graphics is not working. The motherboard does not detect PCI video card automatically. I have to change primary video adapter to PCI from BIOS. But how to access BIOS when there is no display. Is there any method by which I can force video through PCI video card?.........

Comment: Why doesn't the BIOS automatically switch to PCI graphics once it discovers the onboard graphics chipset is shot? Have you ruled out a VGA/DVI transmission issue? Sounds like a SOL situation to me. The only hackish solution that springs to mind is to look for a *very* detailed description of your BIOS somewhere, complete with screenshots, and attempt to blindfold your way through.

Comment: Is there any jumper to force that or any method to change bios settings from another pc?

Comment: Jumpers only reset the BIOS to a default state afaik.

Answer (score 3):

Reset the BIOS settings using the clear CMOS jumper and/or removing the battery. By default, it should use an external video card first.

Comment: But my mother board is an old one we have to change it from bios.

Comment: The default is to recognize an external video card first, so you just need to change it to its defaults. You can do this be resetting the CMOS.

Comment: The BIOS *defaults* to trying an external video adapter *first* precisely for this situation.  For the reverse situation, when the external video adapter fails and the BIOS config cannot be changed, all you have to do is remove the external video adapter in order to revert to the integrated video.  So the *default* configuration is for the situation where you need the most flexibility.

Comment: @sawdust: Plus, that's usually what you want. Generally, the onboard video is inferior to the external video adapter and even in the rare case where you're going to use both, you connect your primary display device to your best video adapter.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz not always true, if you are doing GPGPU number crunching that doesn't produce realtime output you will want your good card to crunch in the background *without* interfering with the display, so you let the weak card handle the latter. But I agree this is a rare case.

Comment: GPU number crunching?? Sounds like the stuff these crazy guys do when digging for bitcoins (new kinda "tech sports", in case you haven't heard of it yet)